# Id increment front-end logic

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.items.push({
"itemId":  $scope.tabId + 1,
"itemName" : itemName,
});
```

I console.log($scope.itemId) every time it get pushed but it doesn't increase.

It could be done to use $http after every pushes but it's good to keep the server light. If for a unque field you don't use auto increment in backend, how would u handle this issue? I mean the best practice.

Comment: A jsfiddle with your example would help a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will always push the same ID (as you recognized) because you never assign the incremented value to `$scope.tabId`.

Change it to something like this:

```
function yourFunction() {
  // increment $scope.tabId
  $scope.tabId = $scope.tabId + 1

  // push the new element to your array
  $scope.items.push({
    "itemId": $scope.tabId,
    "itemName": itemName
  });
}
```